# method call not working after extraction

Tags: java, methods, validation

I have been trying to create to optimize my android code by creating an input validation method then calling it but it doesn't work. I have tried debugging but nothing. 
This is what i had the first time and it was working:

```
String s1 =startTime1.getText().toString();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(startTime1.getText())){
    s1 = "00:00";
}
String e1 = endTime1.getText().toString();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(endTime1.getText())){
    e1 = "00:00";
}
```

but after extracting the validation into this method and calling it each time the user enters input nothing seems to work.

```
public void emptyInputValidation(EditText time, String timeToString){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(time.getText())){
        timeToString = "00:00";
    }           
}


compute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                try{
                    String s1 =startTime1.getText().toString();
                    emptyInputValidation(startTime1, s1);
                    String e1 = endTime1.getText().toString();
                    emptyInputValidation(endTime1, e1);
                    }
            catch (ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }     
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you testing with the emptyInputValidation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `timeToString = "00:00";` of your function you are reassigning the parameter to `"00:00"`, which is not reflected outside of the method. Here is the corrected code:

```
public String emptyInputValidation(EditText time) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(time.getText())){
        return "00:00";
    } else {
        return time.getText().toString();
    }           
}
```

Then simply call `String s1 = emptyInputValidation(startTime1);`

Comment: Thanks for the short hand assignment when calling the method it helped optimize my code!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the annoying parts of how object references and argument passing works in Java.  Setting `timeToString = "00:00";` in our `emptyInputValidation` method isn't reflected outside of that method. Java passes the reference by value, which is somewhat confusing. What this means is that any methods you call on the string to change it will be reflected outside the scope of the method, however, assignment will not.

The easiest way to fix this is to simply have it return the `String`:

```
public String emptyInputValidation(EditText time)
{
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(time.getText()) {
        return "00:00";
    }
    return time.getText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Thanks to your explanation I now understand how to effectively return values from a method or function. I was able to resolve the problem!